# SSRS Deployment Error "The operation has timed out"

Tags: reporting-services, deployment, timeout

I am deploying a SSRS report having size 6229 KB using Visual Studio Professional 2015(Version 14.0.24720.00 Update 1). I am getting an Error "The operation has timed out". My colleague is able to deploy the same report.

Even I can deploy other reports as well.
Can someone suggest me work around for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your colleague using the same tools to deploy?

Comment: Yes. He is using same Visual Studio.